# Rails not responding to ffmpeg commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg

I am trying to run this command here:

```
f = open("|ffmpeg -i /Users/joaoh82/Desktop/teste.MP4")
result = f.read()
```

But I am not getting any response...

But when I try this command in the terminal it works great:

```
ffmpeg -i /Users/joaoh82/Desktop/teste.MP4
```

But now on rails code. Funny thing is that when I try the same thing with some else like an echo $PATH it works great! Like:

```
f = open("|echo $PATH")
result = f.read()
```

Any ideas!?

Comment: Not directly related to your problem but I created a gem for FFMPEG: https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ffmpeg -i` prints to stderr, which won't be captured by your pipe.  You could redirect stderr to stdout:

```
result = `ffmpeg -i /Users/joaoh82/Desktop/teste.MP4 2>&1`
```

Comment: Now I am getting this response...
sh: ffmpeg: command not found

Comment: @Joao Henrique: I don't think it ever could find ffmpeg, but now that you are capturing stdout you can see that.  Specify the whole path (or set your `PATH` appropriately) like @Kelvin suggests.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot man! You don't how much time this has been bothering me! That's how we learn, right?!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify the full path to ffmpeg. It might be working in your shell because ffmpeg is in your PATH.

Basically in your shell, type `which ffmpeg`. Use that full path in your open() call.